# Can we add SCSS file in HTML?

Tags: html, css, ruby, sass

Is there any way that we can use SCSS file in HTML?

I just came to know about SCSS and found that we generally use it in Ruby language, So out of curiosity I tried to add SCSS in my frontend project instead of CSS as SCSS contains more features that are not present in CSS, but failed.

Comment: No you need to compile it before [SASS DOC](https://sass-lang.com/guide)

Comment: Anything is possible with enough JavaScript but that's probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Your browser unfortunately can't read SASS/SCSS. You will need to use the [SASS compiler](https://sass-lang.com/install) to compile it to normal CSS.
But most people don't use SCSS on its own and use a module bundler like Vite

Hope this helps!